# What is the invention of this patent?

Tags: us8386259

In reference to the patent: [US8386259](https://www.google.com/patents/US8386259) I would ask what is invention, as described patent is nothing more than already know Two Factor Authentication method (2FA).

If we take a look at definition of 2FA from CNET [2](https://www.cnet.com/news/two-factor-authentication-what-you-need-to-know-faq/)

"Two-factor authentication adds a second level of authentication to an account log-in. When you have to enter only your username and one password, that's considered a single-factor authentication. 2FA requires the user to have two out of three types of credentials before being able to access an account. The three types are:

Something you know, such as a personal identification number (PIN), password or a pattern
Something you have, such as an ATM card, phone, or fob
Something you are, such as a biometric like a fingerprint or voice print"

Any 2 combination of given 3 types can be considered as valid 2FA.

So, patent [US8386259](https://www.google.com/patents/US8386259) is already known to general public and can't be considered as a patent.

Comment: I have no opinion on your reasoning or your conclusion.  However, that CNET article is dated 15 June 2015. In contrast, US 8386259 has a priority date of 28 December 2006. The CNET article is therefore too late to be considered prior art for the patent.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The Intel patent is titled "Voice interface to NFC applications" and all the claims refer to the use of a method involving a NFC reader, a NFC tag having certain associated keywords, a mobile device, and a voice interface. I don't see anything that involve user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you have the patent number correct? Let us look at claim 1 closely:

1. A portable device for processing Web content comprising:
   a processor coupled to a Near Fields Communications (NFC) reader, an audio input interface, a speech recognition system, and memory; wherein:
   the NFC reader to:
   (i) read a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) from an NFC tag attached to an object, and
   (ii) read keywords specific to content of the object from the NFC tag attached to the object, wherein the keywords are previously stored on the NFC tag attached to the object;
   the memory to store the URI and the keywords read by the NFC reader in a relationship to each other such that the stored keywords directly correspond to the stored URI;
   the audio input interface in conjunction with the speech recognition system to be used as a voice assisted lookup mechanism to enable a user of the portable device to verbally request retrieval of the stored URI from memory by speaking one or more of the keywords previously read by the NFC reader and stored in the memory;
   the speech recognition system to retrieve the verbally requested URI from the memory as a function of matching the one or more keywords spoken by the user with the directly corresponding URI stored in the memory; and
   the portable device to:
   (i) access a server over a network to retrieve and display Web content associated with the URI retrieved from the memory,
   (ii) obtain meta-data embedded within the Web content retrieved from the server, and
   (iii) augment the URI stored in the memory with the meta-data obtained from the Web content to facilitate subsequent search and retrieval of the stored URI by the user.

The invention is, generally speaking, directed to using NFC to retrieve a URL and keywords, detecting a spoken command matching those keywords, opening that URL and fetching the data at that address.